Getting coefficients of an element of a free module with basis in Sagemath
I am trying to do some simple calculations with free modules in SageMath, and am finding the documentation and implementation challenging to follow.
For example, I would like to create a free module over $\mathbb{Z}$ with a specified basis, and then find the coefficients of a given element of that module with respect to that basis. I cannot figure out how to do this simple task (other than doing the linear algebra myself). For example: I can create the module as follows:
sage: M = FreeModule(ZZ, 2)
sage: sub1 = M.submodule_with_basis([[1,0],[1,3]])

This gives a module whose elements are all $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations of $(1,0), (1,3)$. I then find a random element, and ask for the coefficients:
sage: ele = sub1.random_element()
sage: ele
(-9, -21)
sage: ele.coefficients()
[-9, -21]

As you can see, what I get are the coefficients with respect to the basis $(1,0), (0,1)$, not with my specified basis.
Can I get the coefficients with respect to my chosen basis without implementing all the linear algebra myself?

You can proceed as follows
sage: M = FreeModule(ZZ, 2)
sage: sub1 = M.submodule_with_basis([[1, 0], [1, 3]])
sage: e = sub1((5, 33))
sage: e.monomial_coefficients()
{0: -6, 1: 11}

